# Any way to show Display Pics in the Reading List in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange-2016

All of our staff have Display Pictures, which is sorta cool but it doesn't show until you click on the email! What would be really neat is if there's a way of showing them to the left of the subject and the preview body line.

Is there a way of enabling this in Outlook 2016/2019 or within Exchange 2016?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am afraid there is no option available in Outlook to show pictures in Message list. You may consider submit a feedback to the Outlook UserVoice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: I haven't heard of such an add-in and cannot find relevant VBA solutions online for this need.